# Kernel 2.6.29 Booting problem

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded

I am trying to get my kernel booting. I had a problem with getting the output of `early_printk` for version 2.6.29. Now I am getting it, but I still do not understand what is going wrong there.

I have posted my previous issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880990/linux-kernel-booting-stops-at-uncompressing-linux-ok-booting-the-kernel).

Here is what I am getting so far:

`RedBoot> exec -w 1 -c "init=/linuxrc config_addr=0x00060000:0x20000 root=/dev/hda2 rootfstype=ext2 ro console=ttyS2,38400 panic=5 debug earlyprintk"
About to start execution at 0xa0008000 - abort with ^C within 1 seconds
Using base address 0xa0100000 and length 0x001d2e48
Linux version 2.6.29-custom (andy@andy-VirtualBox) (gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC) ) #1 Tue Jul 4 12:21:55
EEST 2017
CPU: XScale-PXA270 [69054117] revision 7 (ARMv5TE), cr=0000397f
CPU: VIVT data cache, VIVT instruction cache
Machine: ANDY electronics PXA270 processor module
Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
On node 0 totalpages: 16384
free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c03b7c7c, node_mem_map c043f000
    Normal zone: 128 pages used for memmap
    Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
    Normal zone: 16256 pages, LIFO batch:3
Run Mode clock: 208.00MHz (*16)
Turbo Mode clock: 520.00MHz (*2.5, active)
Memory clock: 208.00MHz (/1)
System bus clock: 208.00MHz 
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 16256
Kernel command line: init=/linuxrc config_addr=0x00060000:0x20000 root=/dev/hda2 rootfstype=ext2 ro console=ttyS2,38400 panic=5 debug earlyprintk
console [earlycon0] enabled
andy_rom_addr_setup: andy_rom_addr set to 00060000
andy_rom_addr_setup: andy_rom_len set to 00020000
PID hash table entries: 256 (order: 8, 1024 bytes)
Console: colour dummy device 80x30
Dentry cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)`

Can maybe someone say what can it be or where should I put my focus?

Comment: `where should I put my focus`, In looking at 4.x version

Comment: @UVV thanks, but have described it in comments of the link above. I could not change the bootloader, and it will work only for versions under 2.6 as I understood. Or with some hacking like appending device tree to the kernel and skipping mach_id